# Composer import zip as installer-path

Tags: json, wordpress, composer-php

I'm interested in a strategy for adding plugin dependency management to my WordPress themes using composer. Not all of my codebases will be git repos, some will be zip files. The following JSON format, when ran from my theme folder (which is what I version control), will add a plugin from a zip file to my plugin directory nicely.

```
{
"repositories": [
{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "name": "example-plugin-name",
        "version": "master",
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://www.example.com/example.zip",
            "reference": "master"
        }
    }
}
],
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "example-plugin-name": "dev-master",
},
"config": {
        "vendor-dir": "../../plugins"
    }
}
```

which is a practical solution if I'm not using my vendor-dir for anything else which isn't always the case. Ideally however, I'd like to specify a folder using installer-path under extras like so:

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "../../plugins/{$name}": ["example-plugin-name"],
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different approaches and consulted the composer documentation to no avail. Help is very appreciated!